# How to remove offensive words from post by php?

Tags: php, html

Assume "xyza" is a bad word. I'm using following method to replace offensive words-

```
$text = str_replace("x***","(Offensive words detected & removed!)",$text);
```

This code will replace xyza into "(Offensive words detected & removed!)".

But problem is "Case" if someone type XYZA my code can't detect it. How to solve it?

Comment: use `preg_replace("#word#i", $replacement, $text);`

Comment: Don't implement blacklists/whitelists. If you start replacing `ass` with `butt`, you'll end up with things like `buttbuttinate`.

Comment: A [clbuttic](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html) case of trying to do the impossible.

Comment: @ Akam : works great! :)

Comment: @Blender - If you do it *right*, you'll just end up with `v14gr4`, `pr0n` or `f u c k`. Of course, conversations about donkeys will be terribly limited.

Comment: You should do all searches and replacements at once, using array inputs for `preg_replace`, as in my answer.

Comment: LOL @Blender `buttbuttinate` :D

Comment: Who do we complain to about the rabid downvoting on answers to this question that's happening for no apparent reason? Who's doing that?

Comment: It looks like deceze is the one downvoting everyone. We should all write him a letter of apology for making any attempt at all to solve a programming question with a programming answer on a site dedicated to programming. Instead, we should have just said, "dumb question, that's impossible, give up."

Comment: @ButtleButkus Who do we complain to? Nobody. There's nothing wrong with downvotes. If you don't like them, don't use this site.

Comment: @meagar that's exactly what I think a lot of potential contributors will do if this site turns into a nitpicky clique of downvoters. Downvoting solutions without having any ideas of your own is rather vapid.

Comment: @ButtleButkus And yet, somehow, the site has done rather well. Downvotes are not new, nothing is "turning into" anything, get over it.

Answer (score 12):

No matter what you do, users *will* find ways to get around your filters. They will use unicode characters (`аss`, for example, uses a Cyrillic `а` and will not get captured by any of the regex solutions). They will use spaces, dollar signs, asterisks, whatever you haven't managed to catch yet.

If family-friendliness is essential to your application, have a person review the content before it goes live. Otherwise, add a flag feature so other people can flag offensive content. Better yet, use some sort of machine learning or Bayesian filter to automatically flag potentially offensive posts and have humans check them out manually. People read human languages better than computers.

Comment: The only sensible answer here.

Comment: @Buttle I have nothing against regexen. I have something against solutions which have so many drawbacks that they don't work in practice. Yes, it's trivial to replace words or letters with other letters using any number of PHP functions. No, this does not make an effective "bad word filter" in practice.

Comment: @deceze and yet... and yet... try posting some "bad words" in a response to a Yahoo News article and what is the result? Obviously, someone things a slight effort using regex is better than no effort at all.

Comment: @Buttle I don't know, what is the result? Please tell me. Does that filter work if you try to write "classic"? Does it work if you want to talk about donkeys as "ass"? Does it work if I swear is another language? (E.g. "mist" is a bad word in German.) Does it help 1f 1 0bfu5c473 my sw34r1n6? In the long term the solution must be very much tailored to the community. If it's a forum type situation, moderators must enforce desired behavior, filters can't. If it's free-for-all commenting, some more Bayesian learning filter may be necessary. None of the other answers even hint at this complexity.

Comment: @deceze My answer will let "classic" pass. Perhaps the regex involved is beyond you. And the fact is, the simplest, most cost effective way to reduce swearing in forum posts is with a bit of simple regex. No solution will ever be perfect. You are sitting here taking potshots and people trying to give a workable answer, while you sit here safely in the comments. Quit voting everyone down and instead post your own genius answer, get the checkmark, and go on with your life.

Comment: @Buttle This is a peer-reviewed system. Your peers criticize your answers and code. I am your peer and I have given my criticism, *as have others.* You don't have to like it, but that's how it works. Seeing how the vote distribution is turning out here, I don't seem to be too crazy with my opinion. I'm just the broadest target for you since I leave so many comments.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with whitelists/blacklists is—as other users have pointed out—your users will make it their priority to find ways around your filter for satisfaction rather than using your website for what it was intended for, whatever that may be.

One approach would be to use Google’s undocumented profanity API it created for its “What Do You Love?” website. If you get a response of `true` then just give the user a message saying their post couldn’t be submitted due to detected profanity.

You could approach this as follows:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents(sprintf('http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q=%s', urlencode($_POST['comments']))));
    if ($result->response == true) {
        // profanity detected
    }
    else {
        // save comments to database as normal
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer. I wonder if it passes @deceze's valid-answer-filter.

Comment: @Buttle In fact it does since it starts with the premise that 1) it is by definition difficult and 2) it doesn't try to *replace* words. Whether this is *the* solution I don't know, but the answer is good. In fact, the one upvote is mine.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers and comments say that programming is not the *best* solution to this problem. I agree with them. Those answers should be moved to [Moderators - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) or [Webmasters - Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Since this is stackoverflow, my answer is going to be based on computer programming.

If you want to use str_replace, do something like this.
For the sake of this post, since some people are offended by actual cusswords, let's pretend that these are bad words:
'fug', 'schnitt', 'dam'.

```
$text = str_ireplace(" fug ","(Offensive words detected & removed!)",$text);
```

Notice, it's `str_ireplace` not `str_replace`. The **i** is for "case insensitive".
But that will erroneously match "fuggedaboudit," for example.

If you want to do a more reliable job, you need to use regex.

```
$bad_text = "Fug dis schnitt, because a schnitter never dam wins a fuggin schnitting darn";
$hit_words = array("fug","schnitt","dam"); // these words are 'hits' that we need to replace. hit words...
array_walk($hit_words, function(&$value, $key) { // this prepares the regex, requires PHP 5.3+ I think.
  $value = '~\b' . preg_quote( $value ,'~') . '\b~i'; // \b means word boundary, like space, line-break, period, dash, and many others. Prevends "refudgee" from being matched when searching for "fudge"
});

/*print_r($bad_words);*/
$good_words = array("fudge","shoot","dang");

$good_text = preg_replace($hit_words,$good_words,$bad_text); // does all search/replace actions at once

echo '<br />' . $good_text . '<br />';
```

That will do all your search/replacements at once. The two arrays should contain the same number of elements, matching up searches and replace terms. It will not match parts of words, only whole words. And of course, determined cussers will find ways of getting their swearing onto your website. But it will stop lazy cussers.

I've decided to add some links to sites that obviously use programming to do a first run through removing profanity. I'll add more as I come across them. Other than yahoo:

1.) Dell.com - replace matching words with `<profanity deleted>`.
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19502072.aspx

2.) Watson, the supercomputer, apparently developed a cursing problem. How do you tell the difference between cursing and slang? Apparently, it's so hard that the researchers just decided to purge it all. But they could have just used a list of curse words ( exact matching is a subset of regex, I would say) and forbidden their use. That's kind of how it works in real life, anyway.
[Watson develops a profanity problem](http://io9.com/5975173/ibms-watson-computer-has-parts-of-its-memory-cleared-after-developing-an-acute-case-of-potty-mouth@AnnaleeNewitz)

3.) [Content Compliance section](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934?hl=en) of Gmail custom settings in Apps for Business:

> 2. Add expressions that describe the content you want to search for in each message

The "Expresssions" used can be of several types, including "Advanced content match", which, among other things, allows you to choose "Match type" options very similar to what you'd have in an excel filter: Starts with, Ends with, Contains, Not contains, Equals, Is Empty, all of which presumably use Regex. But wait, there's more: Matches regex, Not matches regex, Matches any word, Matches all words. So, the mighty Google implements regex filtering options for its business users. Why would it do that, when regex is supposedly so ineffective? Because it actually is effective enough. It is a simple, fast, programming solution that will only fail when people are hell-bent on circumventing it.

Besides that list, I wonder if anyone else has noticed the similarity between weeding out profanity and filtering out spam. Clearly, regex has uses in both arenas but nitpickers who learned by rote that "all regex is bad" will always downvote any answer to any question if regex is even mentioned.
Try googling "how spam filters work". You'll get results like this one that covers spam assassin:
http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/spamblock-filter.html

Another example where I'm sure regex is used is when communicating via Amazon.com's Amazon Marketplace. You receive emails at your usual email address. So, naturally, when responding to a seller, your email program will include all kinds of sender information, like your email address, cc email addresses, and any you enter into the body. But Amazon.com strips these out "for your protection." Can I find a way around this regex? Probably, but it would take more trouble than it's worth and is therefore effective to a degree. They also keep the emails for 2 years, presumably so that a human can go over them in case of any fraud claims.

> SpamAssassin also looks at the subject and body of the message for the same sort of things that a person notices when a message "looks like spam". It searches for strings like "viagra", "buy now", "lowest prices", "click here", etc. It also looks for flashy HTML such as large fonts, blinking text, bright colors, etc.

Regex is not mentioned, but I'm sure it's in use.

Comment: This would convert `refugee` into `refudgeee` (if it actually worked).

Comment: ahh hok, let me hold your hand and put in word boundaries.

Comment: *Warning: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array*

Comment: Ok I added word boundary, so now you can undo your downvote if that's why you downvoted it. And if the politeness police downvoted me for using actual cuss words, then they can undo that downvote as well. Thanks.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario did you set up the $bad_words array as I have?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Hey try it now. I made a mistake because I set `$bad_words = array_walk`, but that function works by modifying the original array, not by returning a new array. That's why you got that error.

Comment: Your fugging schnitt answer just demonstrates how fracking easy it is to circumvent crumptasic cuss filters. You're still cussing, you're just using different words to do so. That doesn't make the sentence any better and will simply produce a new sub culture with new cuss lingo.

Comment: @deceze I'm just answering the question, not creating a billion-dollar fool-proof cuss filter. If he wants to make his cuss filter "better", then he can add "ing" and "er" to the regex, or to a database with the search/replace terms. Obviously, anyone who wants to can find a way to post some `$hit`

Comment: @Buttle Butkus: Is there any way I can replace "Suck" but not "Sucker" ??

Comment: @netmaster My answer does that. Try "Suck this sucker because it's delicious." My answer will affect only whole words, not partial words. And please give me an upvote if this works for you. Some lunatic is going crazy downvoting every regex answer he can find.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: You're being downvoted because regex is not the solution. Test your code on `аss` and `fuсk` (copy and paste those words from my comment, don't type them by hand) and notice how it fails completely. No matter how hard you try, you will not be able to filter a human language with just regex.

Comment: @Blender, you and deceze are being foolish nitpickers. The point of a profanity filter is not to eliminate swearing, but to make it not worth the effort. Maybe you two go around using unicode characters or mixes of letters and numbers to get your swearing rocks off all over the internet, but most people don't care. If I let slip an f-word somewhere, I actually don't care if it comes out as #$%@. My answer takes care of that. Do you two just go around trolling and downvoting every single regex question? There IS NO SOLUTION.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: Nitpickers? No. If your filter misses things, it's a bad filter. You think someone is going to edit out a swear word when your filter pops up and says "don't say that!"? No. They're going to replace a vowel with a symbol and post their crap comment. Notice how StackOverflow, Reddit, Facebook, and every other decent site that accepts user-submitted comments doesn't filter a single thing. They rely on other users to flag content for moderators to review. Or do you think the people who designed those sites were too stupid to think of using regex?

Comment: @Blender "If your filter misses things, it's a bad filter." I applaud your spontaneous ejaculation of armchair science fact. Unfortunately, it's bad science, and not fact. There is no such thing as a perfect filter in any sense of the word, and yet there can be a "good filter," one that performs within defined limits. But something will always get through. I agree that user-flagging is a great solution, probably better than any programming solution posted here. But this is a site focused on programming questions and answers. You regex trolls are a group-thinking infestation of this site.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: Like I said, do you think the people who wrote StackOverflow, Reddit, and Facebook are too stupid to use regex to filter out words, or do you think there's a reason for their decisions?

Comment: @Blender Like it says in the FAQ, this is site for Q&A about programming, not about general advice on how to run a website. I think there's another stack site for that. Harassing regex answers to questions there would make a lot of sense. I recommend you go troll over there.

Comment: @netmaster, if my solution worked for you, please check the checkbox for best answer. Or pick someone else's. Or tell us what more you want us to clarify.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: You're still dodging my question.

Comment: @Blender, I think you're confused. I already said that "user-flagging is a great solution, probably better than any programming solution posted here. But this is a site focused on programming questions and answers." Now go troll the webmaster's stack site for regex questions, because this site is for programmers. Sorry.

Comment: Everyone who doesn't understand that this site is for answering **programming questions**, please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @ButtleButkus: If you think my answer isn't on topic, go ask on Meta. I'm done with this pointless argument.

Comment: @Blender I don't know what your answer is. If it doesn't have to do with programming, then it is off-topic. Bye.

Comment: @ButtleButkus - I'd give you +1 for the solution, but -1 for the overly aggressive opening paragraphs. I recommend letting your answer stand on its own. (I'd make the edit myself, but want to make sure you're on board with the change)

Comment: @Chris, I tried to make the opening sound more friendly. I reworded, but did not remove, my assertion that this site should have programming based answers. It should. I'm all for a person saying "you're doing it wrong. Even so, here's how to do it wrong with programming, though I recommend a non-programming solution," as an answer. But if it's just going to be "you're doing it wrong, programming will never solve this," then it should be a comment and it should include "go ask this on webmasters or moderators."

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_ireplace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) function that  Case-insensitive version of str_replace()

```
$text = str_ireplace("flip","(Offensive words detected & removed!)", $text);
```

Comment: Why a post which is offering to remove offensive words has an offensive word in itself?

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ How do you demonstrate the effect otherwise? If you put `f***` in there how do future users know that it's not a literal `f***`?

Comment: You right! But i didnt remove because of this issue about development, no immoral

Comment: Sorry deceze I overlooked that. Buttle Butkus a better word could be "F Word" to emphasize

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ Is it forbidden by Stack Overflow's policy or something? Is this site used by kindergarten students? Your edit basically breaks the code (which was not good to begin with).

Comment: Replacing random substrings will basically corrupt random words. Just read the comments about `butt` under the question.

Comment: I just changed my answer to avoid cusswords by using imaginary cusswords like "fug" and "schnitt", plus "dam" which sounds just like another word. That way the functionality still works and the internet will remain free from bad examples for our children.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: I don't think children are browsing StackOverflow in their free time.

Comment: OK you guys win, lets move on :)

Comment: @Bora: Is there any way I can replace "Suck" but not "Sucker" ??

Comment: @netmaster I guess, no way. I suggest `preg_replace` function

Comment: @Blender I agree. But someone is rabidly downvoting all these answers. So I decided to appease them before they blow up my house.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex replacement and need to add the `i` flag to the end of your regex so it searches your text regardless of case. so..

```
$text = preg_replace("/xyza/i","(Offensive words detected & removed!)", $text);
```

`str_ireplace` can also be used if you don't need complex regex rules.

```
$text = str_ireplace("xyza","(Offensive words detected & removed!)", $text);
```

In fact, the latter is the preferred way as it's faster than regex manipulation. From PHP docs:

> If you don't need fancy replacing rules, you should generally use this function instead of preg_replace() with the i modifier.

BUT, as the commenter pointed out, simple string/regex replacements can break your strings if the substring you're replacing appears as part of another non-offensive word. For this, you could either use word boundaries in your regexes or replace only those words that can't be part of other strings (e.g. the word `xyza`).

Comment: You've either copied Bora's answer or you've both copied it from somewhere else. In any case, you can't happily replace random sub-strings in a text: you'll only break it.

Comment: I haven't copied from anyone, and I have tested that substrings are replaced using `preg_replace`. Will make sure `str_ireplace` also works before editing my answer

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario from PHP docs about `str_replace`
>This function returns a string or an array with **all** occurrences of search in subject (ignoring case) replaced with the given replace value

Comment: Let's say you decide to ban `ass` and `dick`. If you apply on `Cassandra likes Adickta Sinfonia` you'll end up with `C(Offensive words detected & removed!)andra likes A(Offensive words detected & removed!)ta Sinfonia`.

Comment: See my answer. If you use word boundary rules you will not get very many (or any?) false positives. Yes, 'a s s' will get through, but oh well. People will always find a way to be profane.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'str_ireplace' to replace any case sensitive strings
Probable, this will help you

```
$text = 'contains offensive_word .... so on';
$array = array(
  'offensive_word' => '****',
  'offensive_word2' => '****',
  'offensive_word3' => '****',
 //.....
);
$text = str_ireplace(array_keys($array),array_values($array), $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: Is there any way I can replace "Suck" but not "Sucker" ??

Comment: Why down voted? do you think we all guys here at stackoverflow are headed????? to help people like you ??? this is not a place where you dislike / like any question which satisfy your need?? go to some site and learning some basic programming ???

Comment: @netmaster. Yes, by using `preg_replace` with word boundaries. See my answer.

Comment: @punk, I agree with you. Someone is going around downvoting all these answers for no reason and they should be banned from this site. They are not constructive.

Comment: i have reported this guys to moderator.